# How exactly does the ranking system work?

Tags: mercenary-kings

The ranking system in this game is a bit weird, and confusing.

There are Ranking Points (RP).  If you check your status, it will tell you how many RP you have, and how many of them you need for "Next Rank".

However, after doing few side missions, your RP sometimes gets stuck and doing missions won't add RP to you anymore. Then you have to beat the primary mission (one marked with red exclamation mark), and from what I noticed winning primary missions is what actually increases your rank and unlocks new rank missions.

How exactly does this all work? If winning primary missions is what increases your rank, what are "Rank Points" for? Are rank points there to unlock the primary mission once you get enough of them (hence they're capped until you beat it)?

Comment: It's either as you said (PR to unlock primary mission) or a bug. Game is still a pre release (alpha?), so things could change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, yes. Though I haven't poured a huge amount of hours into the game this is what I've noticed.

Doing the normal missions will give you RP until you unlock the primary mission. Then completing the primary mission will give you access to the next tier of missions and allow you to continue gaining RP. This is so you can't just grind low level missions to get gear and then <strike>power</strike> flail your way through the rest of the tiers and miss the story in the normal missions.